# How to freelance in the UK without violating the terms of my visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, international, employment

I am a non-UK student studying in the UK. I have a visa and everything is pretty good, but my visa states that I can work no more than 20 hours per week. I don't want to have any problems, so how can I freelance, for instance, and prove that I have worked not more than allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Tier 4 (students on full-time degree), you have more restrictions besides the number of hours. One of this is no self-employment (which includes freelance and consultancy or creating your own company).

Comment: Thank you, is book writing considered freelance, e.g. Amazon (they have some sort of program, I don't remember how it's called) book writing etc? Where can I read more about these limitations?

Comment: @Anna-Lischen: you can download the full policy guide from: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-application-for-uk-visa-as-tier-4-student. If the link gets broken someday, browse the www.gov.uk/ site. I don't believe publishing is considered work, self-employed or not, unless someone commissions you to write. I also don't believe you'll need a visa of any kind to enroll and publish through Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to have any problems, so how can I freelance, for
>   instance, and prove that I have worked not more than allowed?

It's quite simple, you can observe the hours-per-week cap and further demonstrate that you have no income from UK sources (and no income that can be attributed to UK sources) during your student visa.